# Static front page and orderby

Tags: sort, frontpage

I have setup a Wp_Query on a page template that queries woocommerce products. When ***not*** set as the front page my orderby filtering works perfectly. However when trying to use orderby on a static front page it redirects to the index.php page.

This works:

```
www.mydomain.com/clothing/?orderby=title&order=asc
```

This redirects to my index.php template when clothing is set as static front page

```
www.mydomain.com/?orderby=title&order=asc
```

Its odd because I am able to filter by categories, tags, attributes, meta with no problem even when set as a static front page.

```
www.mydomain.com/?cats=mens&tags=shirts&color=black&price=60,155
```

Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Can we see code?

Comment: I don't see the problem, that's correct behaviour - [`redirect_canonical()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/redirect_canonical)

Comment: I am trying to find out if Wordpress handles orderby differently when on the front page like with pagination you need to use 'page' instead of 'paged' with a custom page query. As far as code I would put it up but its very complex, however the orderby filtering is applied using pre_get_posts and the custom query on the page is built using a shortcode.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic are you saying that is the expected behavior, that you should not be able to sort posts on a static front page, sorry not really understanding. I know if I add a special woocommerce query var ?post_type=product into the url then ?post_type=product&orderby=title will sort my posts correctly but that var causes a rewrite rule to get triggered and it redirects to the Shop page.

Comment: The redirect is the expected behaviour - WordPress will canonicalize the request.

Comment: Is there a work around for this?